# DbSet<TEntity>.Find() - Reflection

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Im trying to:

```
...
int id = 5;
//DB is a instance of DbContext
MethodInfo methodFind = DB.GetType().GetMethod("Find");
var resultFind = methodFind.Invoke(entityCol, new object[]{id});
```

But an Exception is thrown at "Invoke":

```
"Object of type 'System.Int32' cannot be converted to type 'System.Object[]'."
```

Is there a way to call DbSet.Find(params object[] keyValues) with reflection?

---

ps.

*Im using it on a CustomAuthorization attribute, i also accept suggestions to improve this part of code. Im trying to check if a certain register of a certain entity  (using an attribute) can be edited by a certain user by its common "CompanyId" property, inherited from a "BaseModel" (so all tables got this property)*

Comment: try var resultFind = methodFind.Invoke(DB, new object[]{id});

Comment: as for the code itself, it's not clear to me what entityCol is or why you need to use reflection in the first place here

Comment: I changed to Db.Set(entityType).Find(id). Less code and solved my problem. Thanks guys

Comment: entityCol is collection (IQueryable<Foo>)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved that using this:

```
var curEntityPI = DB.GetType().GetProperties().Where(pr => pr.Name == entityName).First();
var curEntityType = curEntityPI.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments().First();
var result = DB.Set(curEntityType ).Find(id);
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

`var resultFind = methodFind.Invoke(entityCol, new object[]{new object[]{id}});`

The second parameter to Invoke in an object[] which needs to contains objects the map the parameters of the Find method.  The first parameter to Find also happens to be an object[] so you need to nest it.

Comment: Thanks! I solved the problem using DB.Set(entityType).Find(id);